# quantile regression analysis

Tags: regression, stata, survey, efficiency

What is quantile regression?  How can I use quantile regression to analyse technical efficiency in rubber farmers?  I also want to use the production frontier.

The response (y) variable is production.

The explanatory (x) variables are tappable tree, fertilizer, chemical, total labour.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Why do you particularly want to use quantile regression rather than other techniques such as some form of generalized linear model (including straightforward traditional "regression")?  What is production measured in, and what is its distribution?  Also, what do graphical techniques show you about the relationship of the various explanatory variables to production?

Comment: To answer your first question, Wikipedia has a good article on quantile regression - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression.

Comment: If you are using SAS, this [paper I gave at NESUG](www.nesug.org/Proceedings/nesug11/sa/sa04.pdf) may be of interest. (It might be of interest even if you  are not using SAS)

Comment: I want quantile regression because for research purpose.also I use STATA.Also thank the replies for you.Rubber yield take as production.